# Python Dataframe: Extract Date from Datetime field -- 'Not Callable' Error

Tags: python, date, datetime, series, callable

Updated Follow-up Question:

Error received after running code below: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'month_name' referenced before assignment

[image]

I have an object column that I converted into datetime successfully called "dtin".  Below is what the data looks like:

[image]

I want to create a new column that extracts out just the month from the dtin column (see screen shot).

Below is the code I tried and the resulting error:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also want to create a third column that spells out the month: i.e. Aug, Oct, April ... how can I do that?

Comment: is dtin already formatted as a date? or is that plain text?

Comment: already formatted as date

Comment: Ok then try just removing '()' at the end of 'month'

Comment: woah! that worked -- thank you! ... why do you need to remove the ()?  Also, how do I get it to say the 3 letter version of the month i.e. (8 would be Aug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment above, you need to remove the () like so.

```
df_EVENT4_6['start_month'] = df_EVENT4_6['dtin'].dt.month
```

This is because 'month' is not a function or method but a property. The () is trying to call something that can't be called.

There are a number of ways you could change to the month name. I would probably define a function and use the apply method.

```
def month_change(mnum):
    if mnum == 1:
        mname='Jan'
    elif .....
    return(mname)      

 df_EVENT4_6['dtin']=df_EVENT4_6['dtin'].apply(month_change)
```

**UPDATE**

My bad, you need to apply it to the other Series.

```
def month_change(mnum):
    if mnum == 1:
        mname='Jan'
    elif .....
    return(mname)

 df_EVENT4_6['start_month'] = df_EVENT4_6['dtin'].dt.month

 df_EVENT4_6['start_month']=df_EVENT4_6['start_month'].apply(month_change)
```

Comment: I tried the above ... but I get an error that says "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mname' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Updated my original question ... please see above (thank you very much for taking a peek)

Comment: Hm ok. Try adding month=month.dt.month as the first line of your month_name_function. May not work, but worth a shot. Otherwise, change it like I did in my updated answer.

Comment: I changed the code to reflect your updated answer ... unfortunately still getting same error